# How can I set the wild card name in the File Name edit box of Fine Uploader Open dialog before opening the dialog?

Tags: fine-uploader

I'd like to restrict the number of files listed in the file list area of the Fine Uploader Open dialog by using the wild card name (see image). Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks!

[Here is the picture of the Open dialog that contains a wild card name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX6Wn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `validation.acceptFiles` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation.acceptFiles). For example, the following will limit the selection to video files:

```
new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
   validation: {
      acceptFiles: 'video/*'
   }
})
```

This feature is only a light wrapper around the [file input element's "accept" attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), which has spotty browser support.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly! I added "acceptFiles: '.usrx" to the validation element, and the File Open dialog added "USRX File (.usrx)" selection option before "All Files" option. Thank you so much! You are the best!